# How to call api to get data in a child component (not a page component inside "pages" directory) in NextJs?

Tags: next.js

I have a layout component contain Header and Footer component.
So inside Header or Footer component, I call function to get data in useEffect(). But it does not work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak6RY.png)

Not even need to call the function. It become error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv69r.png)

I have try in any component is not inside page directory. The same error. I can not see any NextJs document talk about this.